# Take and Send Photo Within Android App

Tags: android, email, camera, message, photo

I am currently trying to take and send a photo from within my app. I have messed around with different ways but I either get the options as to how to send the email before the picture is taken, or not at all. I need to send the picture THEN choose the messaging client. Any help?

```
public class PhotoHandler extends Activity {

private final static int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1;
File downloadedPic;
Intent in;
boolean taken = false;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  if (!taken) {
  downloadedPic = takeandReturn(this, taken);

  if (taken){
    try {            
        Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);            
        picMessageIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(downloadedPic));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent, "Send Picture Using: "));
    } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "sendPictureMessage() failed to start activity.", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "No handler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
  }

}  

private File getTempFile(Context context){
//it will return /sdcard/image.tmp
final File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName() );
if(!path.exists()){
  path.mkdir();
}
return new File(path, "image.jpg");
}

private File takeandReturn(Context context, boolean b) {
final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)) ); 
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

final File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName() );
if(!path.exists()){
  path.mkdir();
}

b=true;
return new File(path, "image.jpg");
}       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this Tutorials

http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-sending-pictures-the-easy-way/

and this documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html